# Ransack - Sorting association in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

Fully stuck on **Ransack sorting with Associations**. Want to sort the list of products from different brands.

**Brands Model:**

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

**Brand Controller:**

```
def show
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
    @q = @brand.products.ransack(params[:q])
end
```

**Brand View:**

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: products_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.search_field :brand_products_title_cont %>
      <%= sort_link(@q, :brand_products_id)%>
      <%= sort_link @q, :brand_products_title %>
<% end %>
```

I can filter on the product.title without problems, but **sorting** does not work. What is my mistake in thinking?

Here is the SQL output after clicking on the sorting by title:

```
  Brand Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `brands`.* FROM `brands` WHERE `brands`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `brands`.* FROM `brands` WHERE `brands`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

  Rendering brands/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (19.5ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`brand_id` = ‚BRANDNAME'
```

Comment: Debugging question: what does your query string look like after clicking on the sort link?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065592/rails-sorting-associations-with-ransack

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in the following way:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :address
end
```

Address looks like

```
{ street, city, state, zipcode }
```

I wanted to sort on `job.address.street`

In my controller I have:

```
@q = Job.ransack(params[:query])
@q.sorts = params.dig(:q, :s) || 'id asc'
```

And in my view I have:

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :address_street) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ransack README has this to say about sorting with associations:

> If you have trouble sorting on associations, try using an SQL string
>   with the pluralized table (`'departments.title'`,`'employees.last_name'`)
>   instead of the symbolized association (`:department_title`),
>   `:employees_last_name`).

In your case, that would look like this:

```
sort_link @q, 'products.title'
```

Comment: Already tried that before asking. Did not help. Also after the second edit from you did not change this. Sorry. How do I get the SQL query from clicking the sorting?

Comment: @Karsten Can you share the SQL query generated? There's not enough information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: How do I get the SQL query from clicking the sorting? It does not show up in the log.

Comment: Do you have SQL query logging enabled otherwise? You should also be able to do `.to_sql` on the query object.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **ransack** for **@brand.products** not for **@brand**

In this case you can try something like this in the View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: brand_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
    # Search if the name field contains...
    <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>
    <%= sort_link(@q, :id)%>
    <%= sort_link @q, :title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not help. :(

Comment: Could you please look at https://sq-41795404.herokuapp.com/brands/1 ? It seems to be worked for me.
The code for this Heroku App is here https://github.com/loadkpi/stackoverflow-question-41795404

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you for all your extra work and actually your code helps me a lot. It is still not working with the code in your answer, but your Heroku solution is working and the problem is definitely in the view. Your code in Heroku that does the trick is this:   <td> <%= @q.result.map{|p| '<li>' + p.title + '</li>'}.join.html_safe %><br/> However if I reference @q.products_title, I get the same error.

Comment: It seems to be the "result" that was causing the problem. The code works with @q.result.. Thanks a lot for your efforts and help. Really appreciated all the help that I got here!

Comment: Does someone know why .result makes all the difference. I´m using Rails 5.